# In SQL Server, how do I print out dates with leading spaces for the month and hour fields?

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement to return dates from a database in a format like these dates have:

```
Feb 25 2015  7:36PM
Jun  4 2015  9:54AM
Sep 17 2015  1:10PM
Apr  5 2013 12:00AM
```

The format of these dates is almost this `MMM dd yyyy hh:mmtt`* with the exception that I need leading spaces rather than leading zeroes.

Here is my attempt to return dates in this format:

```
declare @dt datetime = '2015-06-04 09:54:15'
select replace(format(@dt, 'MMM dd yyyy hh:mmtt'), ' 0', '  ')
-- Jun  4 2015  9:54AM
```

I'm just replacing " 0" with two spaces.

1. Is this a correct way to do this?
2. Is there a better way to do this?

I can't do this in C# because I don't have control over the requirements.  I would probably do the same in C# if I could.

* *Using SQL Server's custom datetime formatting strings which I think is equivalent to C#'s https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx*

Comment: If at all possible I would highly recommend leaving the formatting to the front end. If you customize the formatting from the database you can't do things like sort correctly.

Comment: What version of SQL?

Comment: @ajeh Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)

Answer (score 0):

Run the following script will give you the result you need, the trick is add two spaces between MMM  dd, dd yyyy and yyyy  hh:mmtt

```
declare @dt datetime = '2015-06-04 09:54:15'
select replace(format(@dt, 'MMM  dd  yyyy  hh:mmtt'), ' 0', '  ')


set  @dt = '2015-12-31 19:54:15'
select replace(format(@dt, 'MMM  dd  yyyy  hh:mmtt'), ' 0', '  ')

set  @dt = '2015-12-31 00:00:00'
select replace(format(@dt, 'MMM  dd  yyyy  hh:mmtt'), ' 0', '  ')
```